# Reopen an accepted answer question that is tethered to obsolete close votes and was closed as unclear

Tags: discussion, incorrectly-closed

The question: [Do I need to upgrade RAM from 4GB to 8GB for Android development?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014495/do-i-need-to-pgrade-ram-from-4gb-to-8gb-for-android-development) has created a lot of contentious dispute since it was asked. The question was downvoted once and put on hold for the following reasons.

- unclear what you are asking - 2 close votes
- too broad - 1 close vote
- primarily opinion-based - 1 close vote
- off topic  - 1 close vote

Here is the question's history.

1. I posted an answer to the question and my answer was upvoted, so I immediately closed voted this question: [Why does Android Studio freeze up in full screen mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002916/why-does-android-studio-freeze-up-in-full-screen-mode) as duplicate of it. That question was put on hold and although my answer to it was upvoted at approximately the same time, I deleted it anyway. I am not interested in accumulating reputation points for answering the same duplicate questions over and over again. As I am a reviewer myself, I am not interested in that. As an answerer I am interested in solving repeatedly reoccurring problems.
2. I went back to the original question which had meanwhile accumulated a downvote and three close votes, two close votes for being unclear and one close vote for being too broad. Perhaps these reviewers may be self-disciplined enough to check back on their reviews before the question was closed, because meanwhile my answer was accepted which eliminated the principal reason for the unclear close votes. So I tried posting this comment:

   > This question shouldn't be closed for being unclear because it has an upvoted accepted answer (therefore it is not unclear) and it also shouldn't be closed voted for being too broad because it has only one possible answer, a minimum system requirements answer, and that answer is unique to this question.
3. The surprisingly mean result was that the question was close voted again, this for being primarily opinion based. There is not opinion here, only a well-documented fact. The questioner's computer did not meet the minimum system requirements for Android Studio, and I had already mentioned that fact in a comment. I responded by posting the following comment:

   > This question also shouldn't be closed for being primarily opinion-based. As I wrote in the preceding comment this question has an unique objective answer which should not be misconstrued as opinion based.
4. One more close vote was needed to put this question on hold. The last close vote was cast by WinEunuuchs2Unix who also posted this comment.

   > I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Android stack exchange would give better answers

   Not better answers, just the same answer, plus it's off topic at Android Enthusiasts Q&A because the question is about installing an Android IDE in Ubuntu, not about the Android operating system itself. WinEunuuchs2Unix seems to be suggesting in this comment that I should try to migrate an off topic question to Android Enthusiast's and then they can reject it there for being off topic. That would be useless, so I recommend reopening this question here at Ask Ubuntu instead where it is not off topic.

This is going to be a commonly occurring question, and someone is going to have to ultimately answer it and make it stick where it belongs even if I can't. If it has to be asked and answered again, at least the answerer can refer back to the 4 bullet points at the beginning of this Meta post to explain why it is neither unclear, too broad, primarily opinion-based or off topic, and maybe the next batch of reviewers will not close it. Are we required to subscribe to the belief that this question which now has an accepted answer is unclear or would it be more appropriate to coldly reopen the question and move on?

Comment: Maybe we need a PSA on the scope of [android.se]. People often assume that developing for Android is on topic there, but it is strictly an end user site and Android development questions should be asked on [SO]. As for problems running an IDE on Ubuntu, questions about that belong on Ask Ubuntu...

Comment: The question has been reopened and this information will be posted in an answer in another 2 days,

Comment: @Zanna a post from their mods on their site about scope would suffice, and we can point users to that.

Comment: @ThomasWard agreed... probably there is already such a post... but I'm thinking specifically of the number of times I see comments here saying "you should ask this on [android.se]" when the question would get squashed there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unclear. Question reopened.